# How to pass multiple parameters to selector function?

Tags: react-redux

I would like to make a selector function like so:

```
const selectSomethingById = (state, id) => return state.something[id];
```

I cannot make it to work. I would have some components calling it like so:

```
const something = useSelector(selectSomethingById(id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const something = useSelector(state => selectSomethingById(state, id))
```